# Django/PyCahrm. Relocation project to another PC with /venv can`t find `dotenv` module and can`t to install it

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv, dotenv

I relocate my Django project (mysite) with /venv to another Computer.
On first computer it works good. And where was istalled 'dotenv' module.

In PyCharm i set my Project Interpreter as:
Python 3.7 (mysite) C:\Users\User\mysite\venv\Scripts\python.exe

But 'python manage.py runserver' in new computer raises:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

But in ../mysite/venv/Scripts presence file dotenv.exe.
And sobfolder ../venv/lib/site-packages/dotenv/ too.
In PyCharm-Settings-Project Interpreter in Package list presense python-dotenv 0.14.0

Ok. I try to install dotenv by pip, but it raise error:
C:\Users\User\mysite\mysite>pip install dotenv

```
Collecting dotenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/46/3754073706e31670eed18bfa8a879305b56a471db15f20523c2427b10078/dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Temp\pip-wheel-4a1x88l2\distribute\
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Temp\\tmpz_ip4m3r', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned n
on-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Temp\pip-install-07by3weo\dotenv\setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        scripts=['scripts/dotenv']
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 676, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Temp\\tmpz_ip4m3r', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned
 non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Temp\pip-install-07by3weo\dotenv\
```

I try this: `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but it did`t help

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install python-dotenv
(not 'dotenv'). it works